# Swift: Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'CGFloat' But it can?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having an issue with Xcode where it doesn't let me convert a CGFloat value to Double. I have done the conversions (using Double(variableName) and :Double next to the variable name) and it still throws this error:

**Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'CGFloat'**

Here is the code:

```
var InitialGroundWidth:Double = Double(self.InitialGround.size.width)
var frameWidth:Double = Double(self.frame.size.width)
groundSpeed = 5 + (5 * InitialGroundWidth/2)/(frameWidth/2)
```

Comment: What's the type of `groundSpeed`? I bet it's a `CGFloat`, not a `Double`.

Comment: self.InitialGround.size.width is CGFloat but i converted it to Double. InitialGroundWidth should be Double.

Comment: `InitialGroundWidth` is a `Double`. But what's the type of `groundSpeed`?

Comment: Thank you man, groundSpeed is CGFloat but I forgot to change it and now I noticed it. How can I close the question or make it read only?

Comment: Under the question body, there should be a delete button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a dumb mistake. I forgot to convert groundSpeed to Double. I forgot it; it was CGFloat.